# How to instantiate different parent/child classes conditionally?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

Similar questions were posted and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459270/how-to-instantiate-different-child-classes-conditionally) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057774/instantiation-of-objects-in-conditionals-c) but the proposed solutions don't work for me.

I have three classes with multilevel inheritance:

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model();
    template <typename InputModelType>
    void importModel(const InputModelType &m);
    virtual void process(); 
};

class SpecialModel : public Model
{
public:
    SpecialModel();
    template <typename InputModelType>
    void importSpecialModel(const InputModelType &m);
    virtual void process() override; 
};

class SpecialSpecialModel : public SpecialModel
{
public:
    SpecialModel();
    template <typename InputModelType>
    void importSpecialSpecialModel(const InputModelType &m);
    virtual void process() override; 
};
```

The child model is a special case of the parent model and can be stored in a simpler structure and thus, can be processed faster.

What I would like to do is to instantiate the model, depending on an input parameter `model_type` that is specified by the user, something like this:

```
Model* model;
switch(model_type){
case 1:
    model = new SpecialModel;
    model->importSpecialModel(gm);
    break;
case 2:
    model = new SpecialSpecialModel;
    model->importSpecialSpecialModel(gm);
    break;
default:
    model = new Model;
    model->importModel(gm);
    break;
}

model->process();
```

Using the above code, I got the following errors:

> ‘class Model’ has no member named ‘importSpecialModel’
>
> ‘class Model’ has no member named ‘importSpecialSpecialModel’

The problem is that, the import functions are **templated**, therefore it is not valid to define them as virtual functions in the base class and then override in the child class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use function from the static type of the object.
You may do the following which use the derived type.

```
std::unique_ptr<Model> CreateModel(int model_type, const InputModelType &m)
{
    switch(model_type)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            auto model = std::make_unique<PairwiseMRF>();
            model->importSpecialModel(gm);
            return model; // or std::move(model)
        }
        case 2:
        {
            auto model = std::make_unique<PairwiseMetricMRF>();
            model->importSpecialSpecialModel(gm);
            return model; // or std::move(model)
        }
        default:
        {
            auto model = std::make_unique<Model>();
            model->importModel(gm);
            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
auto model = CreateModel(model_type, gm);
model->process();
```

Comment: @RSahu: `process()` seems not part of the creation of the model, that's why I omit it. I add the usage case to be more similar to OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer! I saw it right after I submitted the question but it took me some time to test. It works! But it seems that std::make_unique is C++14 only, isn't it? I had to compile using C++14. Is there a way to make it work in C++11?

Comment: You may still implement your own `make_unique` or use `unique_ptr` constructor with new.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, using this solution, the deallocation of the variables (e.g. virtual destructors) is not necessary, right?

Comment: With `std::unique_ptr`, base class should have virtual destructor (but you don't have to call delete manually). with `shared_ptr` , it would not be required.

Comment: Thanks again, @Jarod42!

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of [the answer by @Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43942740/434551). You can avoid using a `switch` statement by using a map of function pointers.

```
// Independent functions to import the various model types

std::unique_ptr<Model> importPairwiseMRF(GmType gm)
{
   auto model = std::make_unique<PairwiseMRF>();
   model->importSpecialModel(gm);
   return model;
}

std::unique_ptr<Model> importPairwiseMetricMRF(GmType gm)
{
   auto model = std::make_unique<PairwiseMetricMRF>();
   model->importSpecialSpecialModel(gm);
   return model;
}

std::unique_ptr<Model> importModel(GmType gm)
{
   auto model = std::make_unique<Model>();
   model->importModel(gm);
   return model;
}

// Function to import a model given a model_type and the import data.
std::unique_ptr<Model> importModel(int model_type, GmType gm)
{
   // Define a function type that can take gm and return a Model*
   typedef = std::unique_ptr<Model> (*Function)(GmType gm);

   // Create a map of the functions known so far.
   std::map<int, Function> theMap =
   {
      {1, importPairwiseMRF},
      {2, importPairwiseMetricMRF},
      {3, importModel}
   };

   // If there is a function for the given model_type, use it.
   // Otherwise, return nullptr.
   if ( theMap[model_type] != nullptr )
   {
      return theMap[model_type].second(gm);
   }
   else
   {
      return {};
   }
}
```

And use it as:

```
auto model = importModel(model_type, gm);
if ( model )
{
   model->process();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but 'switch' is simple enough for me. +1 anyway.