# Instantiation of Base class using Derived classes without using pointers in Object definition

Tags: c++

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057774/instantiation-of-objects-in-conditionals-c) i saw all the answers are using pointer to base class(`Base *baseObject`) and then use `new` keyword to instantiate different implementations of base class.

let's say if there is a `Base` Class like this:

```
class Base
{
    public:
           int Id;
}
```

and other classes like this:

```
class A : public Base {...}
class B : public Base {...}
```

is there anyway to instantiate a Base Class object Conditionally but without using pointers, like this:

```
Base a;
if (...) a = new A();
else if (...) a = new B()
```

**Edit:**

Based on comments there is no force to use `new` keyword.

Comment: Using `new` only makes sense for pointers, it is asking for memory to store a class and the pointer will point to that memory. In your last section of code `Base a;` already takes up local memory by being declared like that because `a` is not a pointer

Comment: there is no force to use `new` keyword

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reference instead of pointer.

For example:

```
Derived d;
Base &b = d;
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, when using value instead of pointer, you always get values of the same type. So for this case:

```
Base b;
```

The variable `b` cannot be anything but an instance of `b`. Even if you do that:

```
Derived d;
Base b = d; // d is sliced into b
```

The variables `d` and `b` are different instances. To do the assignement, the compiler must convert the value of `d` into a value of type `Base`, much like this:

```
double d = 9.5;
int i = d; // i is 9, it sliced the .5
```

So you must have some kind of reference, or some kind of variable that allows varying types.

#### Using a reference/pointer

This is usually how polymorphism is done. You make `b` a reference type that can refer to any instance of object that extends `Base`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

This creates a unique pointer of type `Derived`, and assign it to a unique pointer of type `Base`. `b` now points to the instance of a `Derived` object.

If instead you want to use reference, you must have a variable that stays alive enough time to use it, something like that:

```
void foo(Base& refToBase);

void bar() {
    Derived d;
    foo(d);
} // d is guaranteed to die here.
```

#### Using a variant

A variant is a type that can have a value of multiple types. It can only contain one value, so it 'varies' between types.

For example:

```
std::variant<int, std::string> v;

v = 12;
v = "text";
```

So you can use that to create a variable that can vary between derived types:

```
std::variant<A, B> a_or_b;

if(...) {
    a_or_b = A{};
} else {
    a_or_b = B{};
}

std::visit(
    [](Base& b) { /* do stuff with the base */ },
    a_or_b
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

1. the keyword `new` returns a pointer to a newly created object. That's why you need a base class pointer (or specific one) to store it.
2. But the bigger issue in your case is `Base a;`. It already creates an object of the class Base. So you try to assign a pointer to a new object from the derived class to a different, already existing object of your base class.

Just use a pointer and everything is fine:

```
Base* a;
if (...) a = new A();
else if (...) a = new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway to instantiate a Base Class object Conditionally but without using pointers

Sure:

```
if(condition) {
    A a;
} else {
    B b;
}
```